# Linux and mm_struct understanding

Tags: memory-management, linux-kernel

I'm trying to understand low level memory management in Linux on ARMv7: I'm digging in "mm_struct" structure.
I've chosen one of the existing in the system processes (say "bash") and take a virtual mapping of it using:

```
cat /proc/121/maps
00010000-000a3000 r-xp 00000000 00:0f 47580890   /usr/bin/bash
000b2000-000b3000 r--p 00092000 00:0f 47580890   /usr/bin/bash
000b3000-000b5000 rw-p 00093000 00:0f 47580890   /usr/bin/bash
(...)
```

And with those information I know that ".text" section of "bash" starts at 00010000. Now I'd like to compute
physical address of the page frame which corresponds to 00010000.

As I checked mm->pgd[0] for "bash" process is 0xc224c000.  I computed the offset in PGD table and it is 0 for 00010000 address.
Now there is the problem that I cannot understand. I've checked under kGDB what contains 0xc224c000 address:

```
(gdb) x/4x 0xc224c000
0xc224c000:     0xbf814835      0xbf814c35      0x00000000      0x00000000
```

And there is the adress 0xbf814835 which AFAIK should be the address of PTE. Unfortunately it is below 0xc0000000.
I thought that kernel address space is above 0xc0000000.

How to explain that the address is out of the kernel address space?
Maybe I'm doing something wrong?

Second question: why "pgt_t" is defined as:

typedef unsigned long pgd_t[2];

why it is defined as array of two elements?